# How to specify 'named graph' while loading data into graphdb with preload or loadrdf tools?

Tags: graphdb, named-graphs

With GraphDB workbench, it can specify 'named graph' to load RDF. But how to specify a 'named graph' with the command line tools, preload, or loadrdf? Thanks!

Comment: There is no way currently to specify a target named graph when using both tools.

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov any update on this?

Comment: Posted enhancement task GDB-5024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this. I've posted enhancement task GDB-5024.

Comment: Any progress about this enhancement? Thanks @Vladimir Alexiev!